# Change Google Picker DocsView Title

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am using Google Picker API on my website. This is my code:

```
this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
                    setIncludeFolders(true).
                    setOwnedByMe(true)).
            addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
                    setIncludeFolders(true).
                    setOwnedByMe(false)).
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.RECENTLY_PICKED).
            addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
                    setStarred(true)).
            setAppId(this.clientId).
            enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
            disableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES).
            setOAuthToken(accessToken).
            setLocale('es').
            setTitle('Selecciona uno o varios archivos').
            setCallback(this._pickerCallback.bind(this)).
            build().
            setVisible(true);
```

Which is being shown as (names are censored but they are showing as they should):

[image]

The issue is the starred DocsView, which has the title "Google Drive". I would like to change it to something of my choice (the rest of the DocsView have default names) or just "Starred" but I just cannot achieve this.

Does someone know how can I change that?

Comment: Well, you can add GroupView and set label by `addLabel('Starred')`, but this label is visible when the user clicks 'GoogleDrive' first.

Comment: Ye, I have already tried that but that was not what I am trying to do

Answer (score 9):

It is not documented, at least [not here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView), but `DocsView.setLabel` method worked for me. So, try the following:

```
    new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
      setStarred(true).
      setLabel("Starred")
```

Comment: It works on js but in typescript (i.e. with angular 2+), it do not compile on build.

Comment: That's very helpful :) For info for people using TypeScript, compilation can be "cheated" by using that for example : `(docsView as any).setLabel("Tab label");`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not alone in this! You can see in 2014 someone else had a similar issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picker-api/9x5a_VAb73k

I had tested this out extensively myself with different options, and it appears that the field is entirely controlled by Google, because it is in an iFrame.

It *seems* like a bug on Google's part, particularly since it doesn't do any of the localization (although that might be intended since the product is named "Google Drive").

Until Google changes that, it cannot display anything other than "Google Drive".

Additionally, I attempted to report it, which you can see here: https://issuetracker.google.com/73046870